# Values of enum from its name

Tags: java, reflection, enums

For example, I've got this enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
   ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

And i want to get same result as by calling `MyEnum.values()` method somehow by passing its name as some method argument, e.g. `getEnumValues(String enumName)`.
How can i do this?

Comment: There already is the `valueOf(...)` method. Why not simply use that?

Comment: And what do you expect the return type of `getEnumValues` to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know at compile time what the enum class is (you just have the name in a string), then you can use reflection:

```
String enumClassName = "com.something.MyEnum";

Class<?> enumClass = Class.forName(enumClassName);
Object[] enumConstants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the enum's `valueOf(...)` method? It already does what you want.

```
MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.value(testString.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: He wants all enum values, not just one. See Jesper's answer.

Comment: Briefly: I'm using GWT uiBinder and i want to wrap my listBoxes with enum dictionaries by simply passing enum's name, e.g :  <a:MyListBoxWidget dictionary="ProductTypes"/> I need mechanism to get ProductTypes.values() from String "ProductTypes" so somehow i need to get Enum object by its name.

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak: please re-write your question to clarify it as now I'm completely confused as to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`E val = Enum.valueOf(E.class, str);`

or

`E val = E.valueOf(str);`

More information on the default methods provided on enum types can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)

Comment: He wants all enum values, not just one.